# CV Help? endcsname?

Tags: moderncv

https://www.overleaf.com/read/gbpsdwsztzkg

I absolutely don't code and have no idea what I'm doing wrong as I just follow the format, although it is a bit old.

It says

> bit to be read again shouldn't be between \csname and \endcsname

but I don't even know what that means. I hope the problem isn't further back because I literally can't code.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please try to post a self-contained question.

Comment: do not use external  links here, but compare your lines 52 and 53, you are missing `{}` at the end so `\end` from `\end{multicols}` is the argument of `\cvitemwithcomment` and everything breaks

Comment: Kicking myself so much XD thank you for helping this idiot

Answer (score 2):

```
\cvitemwithcomment{2020}{Full UK Driving License}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{2022}{Complete Standard DBS Check}
\end{multicols}
```

compare your lines 52 and 53, you are missing `{}` at the end so `\end` from `\end{multicols}` is the argument of `\cvitemwithcomment` and everything breaks